# Show the following series converges uniformly using Weierstrass M Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that the following series converge uniformly by using the Weierstrass $M$ Test.
$$ \sum ^{\infty}_{j=0}z^{n},\ \ \ 0\leq \left | z \right |< R,\ \ \ R<1 $$
and
$$ \sum ^{\infty}_{j=0}e^{-nz},\ \ \ 0< Re(z)\leq 1,\ \ \ R>0$$

So for the first one I thought of using $ \sum ^{\infty}_{j=0}z^{2n}$ since that is greater than the given serious and use the ratio or root test on it to show it converges and that way by the Weierstrass $M$ Test the first series would converge but when I do a ratio test I end up with $z^{2}$ and I don't know what that means. Pleas any help or hints would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that in your question the indeces in the summation are from $n=0$ to $\infty$ instead of $j=0$ to $\infty$; if they are not then both series diverge, as
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^n = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{m} z^n = \lim_{m \to \infty} mz^n = \infty.
$$

The basic idea for the Weierstrass $M$-test is that you bound the norm of your sum in terms of some convergent series given in terms of a constant; if you can do this then you have that the convergence is uniform.
For the first one note that if $\lvert z \rvert < R$ for $R <1$ we have the estimates
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n \right\rvert \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lvert z \rvert^n < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} R^n = \frac{1}{1-R}.
$$
Note that we can assert the above bound because $R < 1$ and the rightmost sum is a geometric series. The Weirstrass $M$-test then proves that the convergence is uniform.

For the second series consider that if $0 < \Re(z) \leq 1$ then we have 
$$
\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nz} \right\rvert \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\lvert e^{-nz}\right\rvert = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\lvert e^{-n\Re(z)}e^{-in\Im(z)}\right\rvert = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\lvert e^{-n\Re(z)}\right\rvert \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lvert e^{-n}\rvert = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-n} = \frac{e}{e-1}
$$
so again by the Wierstrass $M$-test the convergence is uniform.

Comment: sorry its not from $j=0$ but from $n=1$ does this change anything?

Comment: Not in the bounds I produced. You'll note that I solved the questions for $n=0$ instead of $j=0$ so we didn't have divergent series at hand. What you'll want to do is figure out how to use what I showed to show the series from $n=1$ converges uniformly (hint: the series from $n=0$ and the series from $n=1$ differ by a single term).